# Get results from an async SQL query

Tags: sql-server, asynchronous, ado.net

I am creating a program that connects to a SQL Server database and executes scripts using ado.net (it is not necessary to be ado.net). I need the scripts to be executed asynchronously, that is, I don't want to wait for the result. But I need the results of the script execution after my program exits, because script(s) may take very long time to finish, so I cannot just create an async task with a callback or similar.

So, is it possible, and if it is, how can I get the results of the script(s) execution (rows or errors and similar data)?

Is there maybe a way, when executing a script, to tell SQL server to save the results to some file?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of program? Console app?

Comment: Does it matter what kind of program is it? What does it have to do with a solution to the question, if I am only interested in a sql part of program? Don't console and form apps use 'the same code', except for view/control part? It is actually a Powershell script, but it could be a C# program (Powershell cmdlet). They are both running on .net platform, so I don't see any difference here. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes it does matter. If it was an ASP.NET, there are better / different ways of handling an async operation vs. a console or a forms app. I was asking to get more information - in order to possible formulate a better answer.

Comment: Ok. It is a C# library, or Powershell script, I could use any of them. I don't think that way of handling an async operation matters here, because the scripts might finish executing **after the program is already closed**, so a result of sql would have nothing to do with the program itself at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on your comment above (excluding ASP.NET).

You can use the [TaskFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory(v=vs.110).aspx) to execute a fire & forget piece of code. And assuming you have created a SQL Server Agent job - you can call [sp_start_job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx) passing in the job name. When setting up the job, you the output to file option is in the Advanced section.

Example for console app:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(SomeLongRunningProcess);
    }

    private static void SomeLongRunningProcess()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
            "YOURCONNECTIONSTRING"))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "msdb.dbo.sp_start_job";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job_name", "YOURJOBNAME");
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will try to use this in combination with creating stored procedure from c#: Looks like it could solve my problem, thanks. I will let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by running a scriptblock as a job in powershell (jobs run in a new Powershell session). Scriptblock is containing the code for sql script execution (non-async) and waiting for the result and then writing the result in a file on a disk.

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList $ConnectionString, ...
```

New session is started 'hidden' (no window etc.). And is running until a scriptblock is finished running.